# Textfield not editing text in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have set value in dynamic `textfield` through the controller but it does not allow me to edit value only cursor is moving around the entered text.
 I have tried to set value in this way

```
shippingNameController.value = shippingNameController.value.copyWith(text:name);
```

But before the above solution I had tried this, I'm having dynamic textfield named as Billing name and I want to update the value of billing name in the shipping name.

```
shippingNameController.text=name;
```

this was not working when I have used this it was showing cursor at the start of textfield and not updating the value.

```
new TextField(
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'semibold',color: MyColors.colorPrimary),
          keyboardType:field.type=='STR'||field.type=='EMAIL'? TextInputType.text:TextInputType.number,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          decoration: InputDecoration(contentPadding:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'semibold',color: MyColors.colorPrimary),
            border: InputBorder.none,),
          controller: shippingNameController,
          onChanged: (String val) {
            enteredValue(field,val);
            setState(() {
              shippingNameController.text = val;
              sShppingfieldList[p].fieldvalue=val;
            });
          },),
```

[image]

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should works:

```
child: TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    onChanged: (name) {
        setState((){
            shippingNameController.text = name;
        });
    },         
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 onSaved: (value){
                  setState(() {                     
                  _state = value
                 },
 onChanged:(v){
                _state = v;
                 print(_state)
              },
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

I think if you want to set text then you have to do like this

```
setState((){
    shippingNameController.text = "abc";
    });
```

Comment: the first time I'm setting text and next time i'm editing text by entering value through the keyboard.

Comment: have you tried editing the textfield ? Is it accepting characters?

Comment: what type of condition?

Answer (score 0):

Have you adding listener to the controller. Add the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Use controller with text

```
final TextEditingController _email = TextEditingController(text: '');
```

And set the data on controller

```
   setState: (){
    _email.text = "New Text";
}
```

Code of textfield:

```
TextFormField(
                                      controller: _email,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      autofocus: false,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: green3,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          fontSize: 16.sp),
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: 'Email Id',
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: placeholder_color,
                                            fontSize: 16.sp,
                                            fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
                                        counterText: "",
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                      ),
                                    ),
```